# How to add test steps to test run in ALM TestLab using rest api?

Tags: rest, alm

I have a test set in ALM TestLab. 
I am able to create a test run for each test instance from that test set.

BUT: that test runs don't contain test steps(they are empty)

I found some workaround but I don't like it: 
if I change status of some test instance (manually or using rest-api) when it causes automate creation of Fast_Run for that test instance and it contains all the test steps.

How can I create my test runs with all the test steps?

PS: this is how I create test run

https://alm-server/qcbin/rest/domains/my_domain/projects/my_project/runs

454660 - test id 
380824 - test set id 
3323939 - test instance id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <Entity Type="run">
  <Fields>
   <Field Name="test-config-id"><Value>454660</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="cycle-id"><Value>380824</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="test-id"><Value>453660</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="testcycl-id"><Value>3323939</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="build-revision"><Value>1</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="name"><Value>TestRun</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="owner"><Value>super.tester</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="status"><Value>Not Completed</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="subtype-id"><Value>hp.qc.run.external-test</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="duration"><Value>5</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="execution-date"><Value>2020-10-09</Value></Field>
   <Field Name="execution-time"><Value>08:01:07</Value></Field>
  </Fields>
 </Entity>
```